# Allocate vector of list of structs

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, vector

I have a class that has a member which is a vector of lists of structs and I want to dynamically allocate the lists and the elements inside the lists. I'm not sure why, but for some reason my lists seem to be empty even though I'm adding the elements.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class Weight>
class Graph {
private:
    struct Edge {
        int node;
        Weight weight;
    };

    vector<list<Edge>> nodes;
public:
    Graph(int numberOfNodes) {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < numberOfNodes; ++i) {
            nodes.push_back(*(new list<Edge>));
        }
    }

    void addEdge(int nodeA, int nodeB, Weight weight, bool bothWays= false) {
        if (bothWays) {
            addEdge(nodeB, nodeA, weight);
        }
        list<Edge> edgesA= nodes.at(nodeA);
        Edge *edge= new Edge;
        edge->node = nodeB;
        edge->weight = weight;
        edgesA.push_back(*edge);
    }


    void print() {
        unsigned int i;
        list<Edge> edges;
        for(i=0; i < nodes.size(); ++i) {
            cout << "Node " << i << ". Edges: ";
            edges= nodes.at(i);
            typename list<Edge>::iterator iterator = edges.begin();
            typename list<Edge>::iterator end = edges.end();
            for (; iterator != end; ++iterator) {
                cout << "Node " << iterator->node << ". Weight: " << iterator->weight;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};


Graph<int> generateRandomGraph(int numberOfNodes) {
    Graph<int> g(numberOfNodes);
    int i, j, weight=22;
    for(i=0; i < numberOfNodes; ++i) {
        for(j=i; j < numberOfNodes; j++) {
            g.addEdge(i, j, weight, true);
        }
    }
    return g;
}


int main() {
    Graph<int> g= generateRandomGraph(3);
    g.print();
}
```

It is printing this:

```
Node 0. Edges: 
Node 1. Edges: 
Node 2. Edges:
```

As if the lists were empty. tried to use the debugged to find out what is wrong but with no luck. I come from an ANSI C background and I'm still not sure how the new keyword works. Should I store a pointer to the list inside my vector? Should I store a pointer to my struct inside my list?

Also if the answer could also provide how to deallocate the memory on the destructor of the class I would really appreciate it.

Note: the template is so that the weights on my Graph can be defined as int or float.

EDIT: I just want to add that I was not using any hard-coded pointers before. The code you see here is what I got after a few hours of trial and error to get it to work.

Comment: You have a lot of memory management issues in this code.  For starters, you have a memory leak in your `Graph` constructor.  There is no reason to allocate the `list` (nor the `Edge`) instances on the heap with the code you have written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Graph(int numberOfNodes) 
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < numberOfNodes; ++i) 
    {
        //nodes.push_back(*(new list<Edge>));
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ memory leak
       nodes.push_back(list<Edge>()); // adds an empty list to the vector
    }
}
```

That fixes memory leak #1.

```
list<Edge> edgesA= nodes.at(nodeA);
Edge *edge= new Edge;
edge->node = nodeB;
edge->weight = weight;
edgesA.push_back(*edge);
                 ^^^^^ memory leak
```

To fix it:

```
list<Edge> edgesA= nodes.at(nodeA);
Edge edge; // no need for heap allocation!
edge.node = nodeB;
edge.weight = weight;
edgesA.push_back(edge);
```

`iterator` is a **terrible** name for an iterator variable name.

```
void print() 
{
    std::for_each(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), [](const list<Edge>& l)
    {
        std::for_each(l.begin(), l.end(), [](const Edge& e)
        {
            std::cout << "Node " << e.node << ". Weight: " << e.weight;
        });
        std::cout << std::endl;
    });
}
```

That should fix your output.

You also are operating on a copy of the list instead of the actual list:

```
list<Edge> edgesA= nodes.at(nodeA);
```

You should declare it as:

```
list<Edge>& edgesA= nodes.at(nodeA);
//        ^^ This makes it a reference instead of a copy
```

Comment: I made your changes and it still does not print anything. I was aware of the memory leaks and I was actually doing like you described (without using raw pointers), but it was not working.

Comment: Yes now it is working, thank you. I'm used to Java where everything that is not a primitive is a reference. I know how to use & as "pass-by-reference" in function declarations, or to get a pointer out of a value (for example int j=5; int *i= &j; ) but I have never seen it in declarations.

Comment: Also when I do Graph<int> g(numberOfNodes); in generateRandomGraph should I use a reference here also? the Graph object is allocated in the stack and I then return it to the main function. Does the Graph object in generateRandomGraph gets copied into the Graph Object in main (a big waste of resources since the graph could be huge)? Should I have used the new keyword in this case to have the Graph be allocated in the heap?

Comment: You do not (and actually can not) return a reference from the `generateRandomGraph` function.  You are returning a copy (which will be elided - most likely), which will be stored in your `g` variable in `main`.

Comment: So the right way to avoid duplication is to make my function like this: void generateRandomGraph(Graph<int>& g, int numberOfNodes), accepting a reference to a graph object and modifying it, correct?

Comment: In general, yes.  However, `Graph<int> generateRandomGraph(int)` that returns a `Graph<int>` object it creates will more than likely be optimized by the compiler to *move* the return value, which will prevent a copy as well.  This functionality is only available if you are using the C++11 standard, though.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to create a move constructor for my graph object? Like described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_constructor#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors

Comment: Wow, that is pretty neat. Thanks for all the help Zac

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, there are a number of issues with memory management here, but the reason the list of edges is remaining empty is the code in `addEdge(...)`.

If you change it to this:

```
void addEdge(int nodeA, int nodeB, Weight weight, bool bothWays= false) {
    if (bothWays) {
        addEdge(nodeB, nodeA, weight);
    }
    Edge edge;
    edge.node = nodeB;
    edge.weight = weight;
    nodes.at(nodeA).push_back(edge);
}
```

You will get rid of one of the memory management issues, and also have a list of edges.  For clarity, the previous code was making a copy of the list of edges, and adding the new edge to the copy, rather than the original list.

The other memory management issue that I can see is in the constructor.  Here is a transliteration without the memory management problem.  There are other ways to do this using the [`resize(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) method on `vector` that involve less code (left as an exercise):

```
Graph(int numberOfNodes) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < numberOfNodes; ++i) {
        nodes.push_back(list<Edge>());
    }
}
```

There are a couple of other things that I would do differently, but you might want to take this to codereview.stackexchange.com for a complete review.